# Reduce assignment time in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, eval

I need to make variables automatically in my program. I have wrote the following MATLAB code to make unique variables and assign value to them. However, `eval` takes a lot of time.

```
for i=1:22
    for j=1:54
        s=strcat(num2str(i),num2str(j));
        name1=strcat('wave',s);
        add=strcat('F:\MIT Corpus\train\f',num2str(i),'\phrase0',num2str(j),'_16k.wav'); 
        (eval( [ sprintf(name1) '=wavread(add)'] ));
    end
end
```

Is there any way to make this code run faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Know that `eval` is inherently slow, and rarely useful.

Instead of different variables `wave1`, `wave2`... why don't you use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)?

```
for ii = 1:22
    for jj = 1:54
        name1 = strcat('wave',s);
        str = sprintf('F:\\MIT Corpus\\train\\f%d\\phrase0\\%d_16k.wav', ii, jj);
        wave{ii, jj} = wavread(str);
    end
end
```

To access the cell at the (*i*, *j*) location, use curly braces (`{}`), for instance `wave{1, 2}` is the contents of the cell at position (1, 2).

Also note that I've replaced `strcat` with `sprintf`. Much more elegant, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I could not evaluate `eval` because I don't have these wave files, but without eval line you can do as follows:

```
for i=1:22
    istr = int2str(i);
    for j=1:54        
       jstr = int2str(j);
       name1= ['wave',jstr, jstr ];    
       add = ['F:\MIT Corpus\train\f', istr, '\phrase0',jstr,'_16k.wav'];
      % eval( [ sprintf(name1) '=wavread(add)'] );
    end
end
```

Just this change takes 0.09s on my PC, compared to 0.946s of the original code (without eval).

And u could also probably do this which should be even faster:

```
  for i=1:22
        istr = int2str(i);
        for j=1:54        
           jstr = int2str(j);   
           add = ['wave',jstr, jstr, '=wavread(F:\MIT Corpus\train\f',      istr,'\phrase0',jstr,'_16k.wav)'];
          % eval( add );
        end
    end
```

Reading in parallel could be done as follows (little based Eitan T anwser):

```
% close matlabpool if exists
if  matlabpool('size') > 0
    matlabpool close;
end     


% no of wave files to read
NO_OF_FILES = 22*54;

% preallocate waveCell for files to be readed into
waveCell = cell(1, NO_OF_FILES);


% make ii and jj wave string names to be used 
waveNameCell = cell(1, NO_OF_FILES);

idx = 1;
for ii = 1:22
    for jj = 1:54
        waveNameCell{idx} = {int2str(ii), int2str(jj)};
        idx = idx + 1;
    end
end

% create 6 matlab workers (6 is max default in 2013a),
% if u want more, matlab will give en error
% but will also tell how to change it to more, very easy. 
% Off course, its best to how no more workers than cores/threads/cpus, etc.
matlabpool(6);    

% execute this loop in parallel using matlab workers
% each worker will read one wave file
parfor wavei = 1:NO_OF_FILES

    waveName = waveNameCell{wavei};

    ii = waveName{1};
    jj = waveName{2};

    str = sprintf('F:\\MIT Corpus\\train\\f%d\\phrase0\\%d_16k.wav', ii, jj);


    waveCell{wavei} = wavread(str);; 
end    



matlabpool close;
```

But the bottleneck can be that reading many files at the same time from the hard drive is slower than reading one file. Maybe less workers will be better.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. But I want to execute "wavread" command. This commend read the wave file from input address and assign it to name1. I want to do it faster.

Comment: How can read parallel by using parfor? I will really appreciate, if you could write MATLAB code.

Comment: @amirnemat I added example code for `parfor` how your wave files could be read.